# xpath with contains throws error if string starts with a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm running into a strange problem with nokogiri and xpath. I want to parse a HTML document and get all links by href value and the anchor text they contain.

Here's my xpath so far:

```
    xpath = "//a[contains(text(), #{link['anchor_text']}) and @href='#{link['target_url']}']"
    a = doc.search(xpath)
```

This works fine so far as long as link['anchor_text'] is a string without numbers.

If I'm trying to get a link with the anchor text "11example" it throws the following error:

```
    Invalid expression: //a[contains(text(), 11example) and @href='http://www.example.com/']
```

Maybe it's just a stupid mistake, but I'm not seeing why this error occurs. If I put some quotes around the #{link['anchor_text']} in the xpath, nothing is working.

Edit: Here's the sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Example.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<strong>Here is some text</strong><br />
<a href="example.com" target="_blank">11example</a>Some text here and there
</p>
<p>
<strong>Another text</strong><br />
<a href="example.com/test" target="_blank">example.com</a>Some text here and there
</p>
</body>
```

Edit2: If I run these queries manually in irb console everything works as expected, but only if I put the text in quotes.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
madhippie

Comment: Give us the sample HTML also..

Comment: Oh sorry, I added the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that you are missing quotes around `#{link['anchor_text']}`, like you have around `#{link['target_url']}`. The full XPath should be

```
xpath = "//a[contains(text(), '#{link['anchor_text']}') and @href='#{link['target_url']}']"
```

The reason it appears to work (at least not produce an error) when you don’t start with a number is that the string is being interpreted as a node query. For example Nokogiri is looking for a tag named `<example.com>` inside the `<a>` tag, then converting it to a string and seeing if the text nodes of the `<a>` tag contain that string. If the tag isn’t there (as in this case) then the result of `contains` is always true.

As a demonstration, with the HTML:

```html
<a href="example.com"><q>foo</q>example</a>
<a href="example.com"><q>foo</q>foo</a>
<a href="example.com">foo</a>
```

Then the query

```ruby
doc.search("//a[contains(text(), q)]")
```

doesn’t match the first `<a>` tag, but does match the second and third.

When the string starts with a number, it can’t be parsed into a node query since names starting with digits aren’t valid XML (or HTML) element names, so you get an error.

Comment: Is `'#{link['anchor_text']}'` really going to work? How does XPath know that the `'` before `anchor` doesn't signal the end of the string `#{link[`?

Comment: @LarsH The contents of `#{...}` are interpolated by Ruby first, before being passed to Nokogiri. So if `link['anchor_text']` evaluates to `11example` (in Ruby) then the string that Nokogiri sees will be `'11example'` (with the outer quotes). Ruby handles quotes nested inside `#{...}` like this fine.